# How to create two colums in single listview item in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Even if i put two images in a single listview item, how to make onclick on whether which image on which row gets selected.Any please help on this issue?.

Comment: i have two images in single listview item.If i click one of those images it have to go to next activity.Instead of image selection, the whole list view item gets selceted.How to resolve it..

Answer (score 1):

you can use a base adapter for the listview to know the what you required

```
public class bsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    Activity cntx;
    public bsAdapter(Activity context)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.cntx=context;

    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listview_arr.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listview_arr[position];
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name_array.length;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row=null;
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater=cntx.getLayoutInflater();
        row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        ImageView img1      =   (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img1);
        ImageView img2      =   (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img2);



        img1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                 // your code is here
            }
        });

     img2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                    // your code is here
            }
        });

    return row;
    }
}
```

in your activity set your listview to the adapter as `setListAdapter(new bsAdapter(this));`

Comment: i have two images in single listview item.If i click one of those images it have to go to next activity.Instead of image selection, the whole list view item gets selceted.How to resolve it..

Comment: no no, the whole image not been selected.`img1.setOnClickListener` here in this block you can write code for move to another activity

Comment: [here](http://rakhi577.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/buttons-on-list-view-with-easy-searching-in-android/) is the link. just look at the example and use images inplace of buttons there